# Eclipse won't recognize constructor

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor

So I have a class with the following constructors:

```
public TaxiModule(TaxiData taxiData)
{
    this(taxiData, VehicleUtils.getDefaultVehicleType());
}


public TaxiModule(TaxiData taxiData, VehicleType vehicleType)
{
    this.taxiData = taxiData;
    this.vehicleType = vehicleType;
}
```

When I try to call:

```
new TaxiModule(taxiData)
```

Eclipse gives me an error, saying: "The constructor is undefined." When I click on the little light-bulb thingy for the quick fix, it suggests:

```
Add argument to match constructor TaxiModule(TaxiData, TaxiConfigGroup).
Add argument to match constructor TaxiModule(TaxiData, TaxiConfigGroup, VehicleType).
```

Clearly from the constructor details my call is valid and the second suggestion does not fit.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try switching the order around?

Comment: clean your project

Comment: That's because you don't respect Java brackets conventions.

Comment: tried cleaning, doesn't work.

Comment: It is fixed.. it had to do with where the file was in the project.

Comment: Just kidding it's not fixed...